# All permutations from $S_6$ and $S_7$ by which $(1,2)(3,4,5)$ is conjugate to itself

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

The task is to find all permutation $\tau$ from $S_6$ and $S_7$ such that:
$$\tau^{-1}(12)(345)\tau=(12)(345)$$

I think the answer is: $\{id \in S_6 , id \in S_7 , (67) \in S_7\}$

I would just like to confirm as I am not sure if I understand this topic correctly.

Comment: Well, every permutation commutes with all powers of itself, so you are missing a few

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $$\tau ^{-1}(12)(345)\tau=\tau^{-1}(12)\tau \tau^{-1}(345)\tau=(\tau (1)\,\tau( 2))\,(\tau (3)\,\tau (4)\,\tau (5))$$

Thus you need $$(\tau (1)\,\tau (2))\,(\tau (3)\,\tau (4)\,\tau (5))=(12)(345)$$
Does this give you an idea?

Comment: Well, that is what I know, and my conclusion was the solution that I wrote, but clearly it can't be it since you posted this hint.
Also is (345) and for example (534) considered the same permutation?

Comment: @Marek Yes, if $(a_1\cdots a_n)$ is a cycle, it is the same as $(a_2a_3\cdots a_na_1)$ which is the same as $(a_ja_{j+1}\cdots a_na_1\cdots a_{j-1})$ for any $j$. Re-read the definition of cycle notation if you're unsure.

Comment: So is the solution that I posted fine? If not I am afraid I need more hints.

Comment: @Marek No, there a many other permutations $\tau$ that fix $(12)(345)$ under conjugation. However, comparing cycle structure from each side you already know, for example, that $\tau(1)=1,\tau(2)=2$ or $\tau(1)=2,\tau(2)=1$. Then you also need that $\tau$ permutes $3,4,5$ cyclically.

Comment: so for example another $\tau$ could be $(12)$ or $(12)(345)$ or $(345)$ but $(543)$ would be repeating the same cycle? is that right?

Comment: @Marek Those are good examples. In fact, you should convince yourself that things that commute with $\tau$ are products of the form $(12)^i(345)^j\sigma$ where sigma fixes $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot